# Can some one help me with custom stepper in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[image]

**I have to implement a customer stepper which looks some thing like this....I have done a stepper with out a circle using containers and color,,Now i have to redo the stepper with the right mark can some one helpme to implement this**